# EF Core 3.1 migrations

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations, npgsql, ef-core-3.1

I have a sample application (mdbootstrap.netcore-integrations) that asks me to run the following 2 commands for database migrations

https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/standard/integrations/admin-dashboard-net-aspnet/

```
dotnet-ef database update
```

as per the documentation expected behaviour is `__efMigrationsHistory` table as well as the model tables will be created.. but only the `__efmigrationsHistory` table is actually created.

Second command is

```
dotnet-ef migrations add [migrationName] 
dotnet-ef database update
```

Result is:

```
Build started...
Build succeeded.

Specify --help for a list of available options and commands.
```

> Unrecognized command or argument 'dotnet-ef'

After this I also tried the following command

```
Add-Migration InitialCreate
```

Result:

> An operation was scaffolded that may result in the loss of data. Please review the migration for accuracy.

Finally I tried

```
Update-Database
```

Result:

> relation "Users" does not exist

What will be the correct command/commands to run a proper migration? This is using a code-first approach

Answer (score 0):

With the help of my colleague, I was able to resolve it as follows:

```
remove-migration
dotnet-ef database update
add-migration Initial
update-database
```